# Can anyone explain this array declaration in PHP -> $a{0} = "value"

Tags: php, arrays, syntax, error-handling, output

Hi i am using PHP for couple of years ,

these are the ways in PHP that i know to declare an array

```
$arr    = array();
$arr    = array(1,2);
$arr[0] = 1;
$arr[]  = 1;
```

In an example I saw this syntax and I ran the code and it was valid:

```
$a{0} = "value";
```

but the following code didn't run:

```
$a{} = "value";
```

It gave:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'

How to explain this?

Comment: {} can be used for accessing only

Comment: $arr[] = 1 ;  => appending

Comment: Explain in which sense? Looking into the error message: ***`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}`*** - Which part of it in concrete didn't you understood if I may ask? That is a syntax error.

Comment: Also it is not recommended to use array curly bracket access.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[**From the PHP docs:**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing)

> Both square brackets and curly braces can be used interchangeably for
> accessing array elements (e.g. $array[42] and $array{42} will both do
> the same thing ).

`{ }` is not just for accessing, you can even append elements to the array provided you pass the key !

```
$arr{34} = 'some data'; // <--- Valid
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [34] => some data
)
```

but

```
$arr{} = 'some data';// <--- This is not a valid and it throws an error.
```

The only difference between `{ }` and `[ ]` is that you need to pass the key for the former. Else, it will throw an error: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}'`.

Comment: but $a{} = "value" is invalid , how to explain that

Comment: Quoting the snippet above, "interchangeably for accessing array elements". $a{} isn't accessing.

Comment: There is nothing to explain actually, this is code showing accessing the element `34` and assigning the string "`some data`" to it. (This is also the part where you are wrong - with all due respect.)

Answer (score 1):

It's just the same as square brackets but closer to Perl syntax.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#99015

You're only able to access existing elements this way. As you've already pointed out `$a{} = 1;` won't work.